# Block all ports except SSH/HTTP in ipchains and iptables

Tags: linux, firewall, port, blocking, iptables

How can I block all ports except:

1. ssh (port 22)
2. httpd (port 80)

using `iptables` and `ipchains`?

Comment: While ochach's answer is technically correct, I think you need to clarify your question.  Do you mean "block all input except ssh and http"?  If you follow ochach's answer, you won't be able to do anything - no data will be allowed out of your box.

Comment: Unbelievable that the better thread at https://superuser.com/questions/769814/how-to-block-all-ports-except-80-443-with-iptables is marked as a duplicate for this...

Answer (score 8):

IP chains are old and I do not recommend them.

A simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

#start and flush
$IPTABLES -F
$IPTABLES -t nat -F
$IPTABLES -X
$IPTABLES -P FORWARD DROP
$IPTABLES -P INPUT   DROP
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT  ACCEPT

#SSH traffic
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
#HTTP traffic
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

#loopback
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i lo -p all -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I ran this script on my server and locked myself out :)

Comment: @Zilupe 
to easily not loose acces to server remember to use cron while editing firewall - like:
*/2 * * * * iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT

Comment: SSH requires 40 seconds to connect with your rules, against 3 seconds without. I suspect you drop DNS resolution capabilities too.

Comment: Missing these 2 lines

iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack -m cpu -j ACCEPT  --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 8):

Which Linux distribution? You may be better off using a higher level firewall like ufw:

As root/sudo:

```
ufw default deny
ufw allow ssh
ufw allow http
ufw enable
```

Comment: This is a worthwhile option but consider providing instructions on how to block all incoming traffic except ssh and http, please.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ufw` to block everything by default but allow ssh and http/https:

```bsh
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw allow 22
sudo ufw allow 80
sudo ufw allow 443
sudo ufw enable
```

Also remember that by default Docker and ufw don't work well together, you'll need to change the Docker daemon config as described there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49563279/561309